# Mesh a circle with quadrilateral elements

Tags: numerical-methods, meshing

I'm having some problems understanding an exercise. The domain $\Omega$ is the unit circle. Then it says:

"To mesh it with quadrilateral elements, compose $\Omega$ from five mapped squares,
one of them being a square centered at the origin. Propose five analytical mappings, one for each square."

How is that supposed to look like? Am I mapping a cross kinda thing into a circle? And why squares and not a triangular mesh? Where are the benefits to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's (very roughly) what it looks like. The nearly-adjacent lines should be single lines, of course.

[image]

Why squares? Because this particular exercise is about meshing with quadrilateral elements. Why are quad elements sometimes good? Beats me...I don't work on meshes much.